# How to split string at <div></div>

Tags: php, html

I have stored some strings in mysql table, in this form (in a Single column) -

```
<div id='ques'>Question 1 is written here</div>
<div id='opt1'>Text of option 1</div>
<div id='opt2'>Text of option 2</div>
<div id='opt3'>Text of option 3</div>
<div id='opt4'>Text of option 4</div>
<div id='opt5'>Text of option 5</div>
<div id='opt6'>Text of option 6</div>
```

For some reasons I can't use separate columns (to store) for these divs', **All the demo code written above is in a Single column (or Cell to be correct) of table.** So, the divs themselves are a part of single huge string. Therefore string would be like,

```
$question_set="<div id='ques'>Question 1 is written here</div><div id='opt1'>Text of option 1</div><div id='opt2'>Text of option 2</div><div id='opt3'>Text of option 3</div><div id='opt4'>Text of option 4</div><div id='opt5'>Text of option 5</div><div id='opt6'>Text of option 6</div>"
```

**What I want is to split text at each div, and store its innerHtml value in its counter php variable**, i.e. like,

```
$question="Question 1 is written here";
$option1="Text of option 1";
```

and so on...

**Edit - 1**
Some of you wanted, if I have done research, here is what i could do my best -

```
list($question, $option1, $option2, $option3, $option4, $option5, $option6) = split('</div>', $question_set);
echo $question;
echo "<br>";
echo $option1;
```

also, similar result was achieved by -

```
list($question, $option1, $option2, $option3, $option4, $option5, $option6) = explode('</div>', $question_set);
```

and so on..

**Note** - i didn't post it earlier for many reasons, biggest of which is if you go by my name/profile I am a **doctor of human beings**, Not even a student of programming. I dint want to deviate my discussion earlier as Not only above mentioned method is working for me to an extent giving me some other problems, but also my wamp server says "Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated"
anyways
Thanks. Regards,

Comment: Can you post your so far effort to achieve that ?

Comment: How does it know what the variables are meant to be called?

Comment: @Rikesh edited my question, with the effort

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D39Yx/)**
  use    **[map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)**   in jquery to retrieve the value in array

```
var collect = $("div").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
}).get();

//console.log(collect[0]);
//console.log(collect[1]);
//console.log(collect[2]);.............

// **$.each()**

//$.each(collect,function(i,val){
      //console.log(i+ "  "+ val);
    //});
```

Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

Comment: The question is about php!

Comment: @colburton : question is tagged `js` too... :)

Comment: @bala : +1, please add some explanation too, for Noobs like me!! :)

Comment: @colburton i tagged it with js and jquery, because it would be good if they can serve the purpose

Comment: @balachandran i think `map` is grouping all of them. i need reverse. they all are grouped into one string. i need them separated.

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari Basically collect is an array you know..?

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari based on the index you can get corresponding values like collect[0] is a question  ,collect[1] is a option 1

Comment: @balachandran sorry, my bad, I noticed it soon after i commented, but then i went to edit my question with my effort. Your code works, but the real problem here is that you have kept all the `divs` in html(in your fiddle), while in reality they are grouped together in `$question_set`. So, the `map` function can be best for `div` but how to call that for `divs` in `php string'?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with regex:
 with a preg_replace you remplace the two div tags by nothing so you simply keep the question

The regex to find what's inside the div would be like

```
^(<div id=\'[a-z0-9]+\'>)([^<>]+)(</div>)
```

then you remplace with the following pattern: `$2`, it will only keep the things beetweed the div... I didn't tested it but it should work
Note that you have to apply this for each line.

Answer (score 0):

A php solution, where question is stored in `$question` and the other options in `$opts` array.

```
$question_set="<div id='ques'>Question 1 is written here</div><div id='opt1'>Text of option 1</div><div id='opt2'>Text of option 2</div><div id='opt3'>Text of option 3</div><div id='opt4'>Text of option 4</div><div id='opt5'>Text of option 5</div><div id='opt6'>Text of option 6</div>";
$q_pattern = "#<div id='ques'>([a-zA-Z0-9 _?-]{0,})<\/div>#";
$o_pattern = "#<div id='opt[0-9]{0,}'>([a-zA-Z0-9 _?-]{0,})<\/div>#";
preg_match($q_pattern, $question_set, $q_match);
preg_match_all($o_pattern, $question_set, $o_match);
$question = $q_match[1];
for ($i=0; $i < count($o_match[1]); $i++) { 
    $opts[] = $o_match[1][$i];
}
print_r($opts);
print_r($question);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Text of option 1
    [1] => Text of option 2
    [2] => Text of option 3
    [3] => Text of option 4
    [4] => Text of option 5
    [5] => Text of option 6
)
```